# Prove, for a Poisson Random Variable, P[X=k] is maximized at lambda

Tags: probability

If X ∼ Poisson (λ), prove that P[X = k] is maximized at k = λ

How would I go about proving something like this so that the method would work to prove a maximization point of other random variables like say Binomial is max at k = (n+1)*p?

Comment: Are you assuming that $\lambda$ is an integer?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an integer (which is usually not the case) then there are two maxima, at $k=\lambda-1$ and $k=\lambda$.

Comment: There are no assumptions

Comment: If $\lambda$ is not an integer then $\mathbb P(X=\lambda)=0$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: what is $P(X=k)/P(X=k+1)$?

Comment: That would be $$\frac{e^\lambda}{\lambda}$$, right? How does that help me know that this is a maximum?

Comment: The expression that Dr. Israel has suggested will depend on $k$, and it has the property that it will be less than one if and only if $P(X=k) \lt P(X=k+1)$.